# Using two "that" clauses

Tags: word-usage, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

The following sounds correct to me but that is always the case with mistakes ;)

> I spend a lot of time making sure that everything is clean, that
>   everything is as it should be.

Were the two "that" clauses used correctly? Should there be a different punctuation separating the two? My intent is to underscore the importance of the state of things. As such, using only one of the two clauses isn't viable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage is correct! Your second "that clause" is what is known as an *[adjective clause](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/adjclterm.htm)*, or a clause that is used to add description to the word that comes before it.

In your example, the clause *that everything is as it should be* is adding a description to the word *clean*. What you are saying is that when you say *clean*, you mean *that everything is as it should be*.

More specifically, the clause in question is a *[non-essential adjective clause](http://flang1.kendall.mdc.edu/4/414/L414lecture2/essentialClauses.htm)*, which means that it is additional information that doesn't change the clarity of the sentence if it is removed. Non-essential adjective clauses start (and end) with a comma, to separate them from the rest of the sentence.